# Obter Logradouro e número numa string numa expressão irregular

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, tsql

Tenho uma tabela que tenho todo o endereço em uma só coluna, porém a mesma é irregular. Segue abaixo algumas das ocorrências:

> ```
> BR 459 KM 153
> RODOVIA ITAJUBA MF KM 05
> Rodovia MG353  2Km 55
> RUA 37 QUADRA 4 LOJA 611 E 1621
> Rua 13 de Maio 71C
> RUA 106 Nº07
> RUA 114 08
> ```

Qual a forma mais correta para extrair para esses casos o Logradouro e o Número jé que temos o nome da Rua/Rodovia com número e outras informações que podem ser descartadas? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Sem um padrão não tem como fazer isso... poderia fazer um *regular expression* que encontrasse a primeira ocorrência de um número, mas esse pode ser parte do nome do logradouro. Talvez você tenha que fazer um dicionário de descrições para o logradouro, como *"Rua, Avenida, Rodovia"*, etc para ajudar a identificar o logradouro, mas mesmo assim não vai ter algo 100% preciso para separar logradouro e número

Comment: A "forma mais correta" é recadastrar certo. No seu caso dá para automatizar a maior parte das ocorrências, e tratar manualmente as exceções

Comment: Exato, consegui desenvolver uma solução provisória, mas não é adequada, o certo seria melhorar a interface permitido a entrada dos dados dentro do padrão.

Comment: Eu faria uma function que retornaria o endereço "quebrado" na function fica mais fácil tratar os diferentes casos retornaria ou um tipo complexo ou uma string seperada por vírgulos , outra aplicação se encarregaria de gravar os dados.

Comment: Eu montaria um script separando primeiramente os tipo de logradouros, exemplo: pegaria a primeira palavra de cada ocorrência, verificaria se era "Rua", "Avenida", "Viela", "BR", "Praça".... e gravaria em uma temporária com o tipo. No fim eu teria separado  quase, ou todos os endereços e os que sobrassem eu trataria individualmente.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?